# MySQL add unique constraint on columns from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's an example for what I am looking to do :

I have 3 tables :

- Villages (id, name)
- Households (id, village_id)
- Persons (first_name, last_name, household_id)

I would like to make sure there isn't 2 persons who have the same first name and last name in the same village.

Basically I would like to do something of that sort :

```
ALTER TABLE persons 
 ADD UNIQUE (first_name, last_name, households.village_id 
            WHERE household_id=households.id)
```

Is there a way to do something like that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do that directly, but if this is to store real-world data it is theoretically possible for two people with identical name to live within a village, so this may not be the best idea?

If you insist on going down this route then I recommend using a STORED PROCEDURE to handle inserts to this table taking in arguments such as user name and village.  The stored procedure could then do a SELECT prior to INSERT to check for conflicts.  This would take the place of any INSERT queries.  UPDATEs would also need handling via procedure to prevent clashes.

Comment: Hi Simon ! Thank you for your answer. The reason why it seems to me more strategic to go this way, is because for our company it seems to be more worth it to handle exceptions when it happens that several persons have the same name in one village, then to take the risk of users creating duplicates and messing up with the data. Your solution sounds good, I'll look into it in more details. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no simple way to do that.

You might wanna try creating triggers on before insert/update and throw error on your custom condition. But it is highly dependant on your MySQL version: prior to version 5.5, I believe there is no correct way to raise an error - usually people use hacks like calling non-existent procedures. But if you are on version >5.5 you can use SIGNAL statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html